# テストデータに使用するダミーの電話番号の探し方

Tags: テスト

テストアカウントに使用する電話番号についてお伺いしたいです。
テストアカウントの電話番号にダミーデータとして080-xxxx-xxxxや0120-xxx-xxxを使用したいのですが実際に使用されていない、かつ今後も使用されることのない電話番号を探しています。
どなたかご存じの方がおられましたらご教授頂けますと幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「電話番号 テスト用」で検索するだけでも、それらしい解説をしたページが見つかります。 https://stabucky.com/wp/archives/6180

Answer (score 5):

コメントにある[解説サイト](https://stabucky.com/wp/archives/6180)によると0120や0800の着信課金用電話番号(いわゆるフリーダイヤル)に「今後も存在しない電話番号」は存在しないようです。

総務省の[電気通信番号指定状況](https://www.soumu.go.jp/main_sosiki/joho_tsusin/top/tel_number/number_shitei.html)から、
「2. 付加的役務電話番号 → ・着信課金機能」の一覧表を見ても`0120-000-GHJ`～`0120-999-GHJ`および`0800-000-GHJK`～`0800-999-GHJK`(`GHJK`は不特定の十進数)がすべて表内に枠が存在する項目であることがうかがえます。(後述の通り未予約の付加的役務識別番号枠はあります)

上記の範囲内に空きがないことは[電気通信番号計画（令和元年総務省告示第６号）](https://www.soumu.go.jp/main_content/000620706.pdf)PDFのp6.『第３ 利用者設備識別番号に関する事項』表内の『付加的役務電話番号』ルールから読み取れるはずです。
ただし、表内の予約されていない番号帯(たとえば`0120-902-XXXX`など)は**2021年9月30日時点では存在しない**番号のように思えます。

なお回答文が伝聞・推定の表現である通り、回答者の私は素人です。
この回答の誤りや今後の付加的役務識別番号追加により**実在する番号でありうる**ことを強調させていただきます。

Answer (score 3):

目的は何でしょうか。

ダミーのユーザー情報など「実データを使ってはいけない」ぐらいのレベルのテストデータであればランダム番号でも十分です。氏名と同様、実在の電話番号と偶然に一致する可能性がありますが、それは普通問題にはなりません。

架電やSMS送信など、万が一にも実番号に発信してはいけないようなテストで用いるテストデータであれば、

- 閉鎖環境(絶対に外部に発信しない)ではランダム番号等でテスト
- 実環境で自社保有の電話番号でテスト

などの2段階でデータを変えてテストするなどやりかたを考える必要があります。

会社ルール等で「非実在が保証されるデータ」の使用が義務づけられているなら、ルールを決めた部門にそこが問題ないと保証してくれるテスト用データの作成を依頼した方がよいでしょう。